# HTML 5 Video not working on Ipad and ipad layout has black portions on the side

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, html, html5-video

I am stuck on an HTML 5 Project where the video works on Chrome and Safari PC browser but not on the iPad. The requirement is to make this work on portrait mode only and When the video is tapped/clicked, the video will play.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE e 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en">  <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en">         <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en">                <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en">                       <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Page 1</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=768px, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"   />
        <style>
            #container{
                width:768px;
                margin:150px auto;
                position: relative;
            }
            #container video {
                position:relative;    
                z-index:0;
            }
            .overlay {
                position:absolute;
                top:170px;
                left:380px;
                z-index:1;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            function play(){
                var video = document.getElementById('video');
                video.addEventListener('click',function(){
                    video.play();
                },false);
            }
    </script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                function reorient(e) {
                    var portrait = (window.orientation % 180 == 0);
                    $("body > div").css("-webkit-transform", !portrait ? "rotate(-90deg)" :       "");
                }
                window.onorientationchange = reorient;
                window.setTimeout(reorient, 0);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <video id="video" width="770" height="882" onclick="play();">
                <source src="video/Motionv4-1.m4v" />
            </video>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div style="color:#356AFA; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-size:45px; line-height:60px; font-family:arial">
                    Tap the <br /> DoughBoy<br />to Join<br /> JavaWorld<br /> Wi-Fi!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I was working on this type of projects.

I had used jwplayer to fix this.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/

Answer (score 0):

well iPad has a bug where it only looks at the first mime time provided so you need to add your .mp4 file first then only it will work.

more info here. http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html